# How to idiomatically call C++ functions based on variable value?

Tags: c++, templates, repeat

Suppose I have a data type `enum TreeTypes { TallTree, ShortTree, MediumTree }`.

And I have to initialize some data based on one particular tree type.

Currently I have written this code:

```
int initialize(enum TreeTypes tree_type) {
    if (tree_type == TallTree) {
        init_tall_tree();
    }
    else if (tree_type == ShortTree) {
        init_short_tree();
    }
    else if (tree_type == MediumTree) {
        init_medium_tree();
    }
    return OK;
}
```

But this is some kind of stupid code repetition. I am not using any of the powerful C++ capabilities like templates.

How could I write this code better?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: Looks like improving your code should start from the design. You can try to replace good old control structure like if(){}else{} with some clever use of other language features, but I doubt it will improve the code. Write more about the problem itself. What are you trying to model.

Comment: The code I am using is more complex. I tried to simplify it with very small example. I am working on very large project and in one place user can have various data types (here I called them TallTree, ShortTree, MediumTree). And for every data type I have to do some action. In my case it's 12 different types so my if/else if/else if/ is 12 different if/else if/... statements. Very bad.

Comment: But where does the tree_type argument came from when you actually call initialize. Is initialize a normal function or a method of some class? Do those init functions act on some global data? What do they initialize. There are no parameters. Are they methods?

Comment: I simplified that too. They all take the same 3 parameters. The tree_type argument comes from user input, depending on which action user chooses. Once he chooses it, I have to initialize the dialog for him (this is what tree_type is actually -- dialog type), and the initialization function takes the pointer to window to initialize the dialog on, pointer to user's information and log data structure (where previous actions are kept, so he could undo tasks).

Comment: So what I was thinking, was one function like "initialize" and I wanted to template parematrize it on tree_type like `initialize<tree_type>(window, user_info, logger)` and have individual template specializations like `template <> bool initialize<TallTree>(Window *w, UserInfo *u, Logger *l)` but that doesn't quite work. I can't call template with a variable `tree_type`.

Comment: Yes. To use templates like that tree_type must be known at compile time. If it comes from the user you can't help it. You have to select the function somehow at runtime. It can be map as Neil suggests, but the map must be initialized somewhere, so the code linking type to function has to be written. It's not good if it has to be written over and over again. If you find yourself writing it over and over again something should be changed.

Comment: I will try Remy Lebeau's suggestion of using an array (map) of function pointers. (same as Neil suggests)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code is OK for two or three values, but you are right, you need something more industrial strength when you have hundreds of them. Two possible solutions:

- use a class hierarchy, not enums - you can then use virtual functions and have the compiler work out which actual function to call
- create a map of enum -> function, which you initialise at startup - your function calls then become something like `map[enum]->func()`

Templates don't work so well here, because you are trying to make a decision at run-time, whereas templates do their stuff at compile-time.

Comment: The function map can benefit from using `boost::function`/`boost::bind()` or the TR1 equivalents.

Comment: This sounds like a vtable, C++ already has this with virtual functions and polymorphism...

Comment: @josh Golly, isn't  that just what my answer says?

Comment: @Neil sorry, misread; I guess my eye was drawn to the map[enum] part.

Comment: If there are hundreds of values, going with the first idea means hundreds of subclasses; is this really such a good idea?

Answer (score 8):

In one word: inheritance

```
class Tree { public: virtual void initialize() = 0; }

class ShortTree : public Tree {
public:
    virtual void initialize(){
        /* Short Tree specific code here */
    }
}

class MediumTree : public Tree {
public:
    virtual void initialize(){
        /* Medium Tree specific code here */
    }
}

class TallTree : public Tree {
public:
    virtual void initialize(){
        /* Tall Tree specific code here */
    }
}
```

Then wherever you want to call initialize just make sure to have a pointer or a reference for polymorphism to work correctly:

```
Vector<Tree*> trees;
trees.push_back(new SmallTree());
trees.push_back(new MediumTree();
trees.push_back(new TallTree();

// This will call the tree specific code for each tree in the vector
for(vector<Tree*>::iterator tree = trees.begin(); tree!=trees.end(); ++tree)
    tree->initialize();
```

Comment: Your base class had better have a virtual destructor, assuming you ever call delete on the things you have new'd.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth My code has been taken and run with...I don't recognize it anymore :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a lookup table that is indexed by the enum values (assuming all of the functions have the same signature), ie:

```
enum TreeTypes { TallTree, ShortTree, MediumTree, MaxTreeTypes }

typedef void (*p_init_func)(void); 

p_init_func initialize_funcs[MaxTreeTypes] =
{
    &init_tall_tree, 
    &init_short_tree,
    &init_medium_tree
};

int initialize(enum TreeTypes tree_type)
{ 
    initialize_funcs[tree_type]();
    return OK; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And the template way since you have pointed it in your tags:

```
enum TreeTypes { Tall, Short, Medium };

struct TreeBase {
    // (...)
};

struct TallTree : public TreeBase {
    // (...)
};

struct ShortTree : public TreeBase {
    // (...)
};

struct MediumTree : public TreeBase {
    // (...)
};

template<TreeTypes N_type = Tall>
struct Tree : public TallTree {
    // (...)
};

template<>
struct Tree<Short> : public ShortTree {
    // (...)
};

template<>
struct Tree<Medium> : public MediumTree {
    // (...)
};
```

That way you got seperate classes for each tree type which can be accessed by base pointer. Wrapping them into Tree class let you do this:

```
Tree<Tall> tall_tree;
Tree<Short> short_tree;
Tree<Medium> medium_tree;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this initialization is really the only distinction, then I'm not sure any other idiom would improve the situation.

You could subclass from Tree and create the right sort of tree object...but you'd still need to differentiate which one to instantiate, so you'd still wind up with a similar if/else block, somewhere.

That said, if there is more than just initialization that'd different, you should subclass and use virtual functions to enact the differences between them.

Answer (score -1):

Try a switch statement:

```
int initialize(enum TreeTypes tree_type) {
    switch (tree_type) {
        case TallTree: 
            init_tall_tree();
            break;
        case ShortTree:
            init_short_tree();
            break;
        case MediumTree:
            init_medium_tree();
            break;
    }
    return OK;
}
```